# Laravel5 crontab with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 error when running schedule

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, mcrypt

I have a working Laravel5 copy and everything works, and by that I mean I have ran all of these command without crontab and all of them work fun. When I run my schedule with crontab I get an Error of:

```
Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'
```

What I am doing in my schedule is just testing with my own email that the schedule will send it to me. My crontab looks like:

```
\* \* \* \* \* php /my/artisan/location/artisan schedule:run >> /my/log/location/newLog123.txt
```

when I run 'php artisan schedule:run' it works perfecting. when the time on schedule is up it sends out email. So it is not an issue with that, but with the crontab task itself. I am not sure if I have to specify other locations, I know crontab runs from my home dir, so maybe I have to specify something else? I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did figure this one out, the environment that crontab was running php in was using a different php location then what I was using, so how I fixed it was just tell it which php to use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the `mcrypt` module of PHP5 disabled. This module defines the constants used in encryption, and the required functionality.

Enable it using `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`.

It also seems that your problem has nothing to do with the cronjob.

Comment: I have tried this, and nothing, how is it not a cronjob problem? I can run `php artisan schedule:run` and it will run successfully, when the crontab runs it it give error only with there is a schedule to run in laravel, however they should be running the same things with sam env.